# List names of all tables in a SQL Server 2012 schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a schema in SQL Server 2012.

Is there a command that I can run in SQL to get the names of all the tables in that schema that were populated by user?

I know a similar query for MySQL `SHOW TABLES;` but this does not work with SQL Server.

Comment: What does "*populated by user*" mean?  Its very ambiguous in this context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL statement to grab table names, views, and stored procs, order by schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516173/sql-statement-to-grab-table-names-views-and-stored-procs-order-by-schema)

Comment: What I meant by that was, some tables are created by the system and some are created by the code written and executed by the program for which the user is using the database. Sorry for being ambiguous. But I found the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 86):

Your should really use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views in your database:

```
USE <your_database_name>
GO
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

You can then filter that by table schema and/or table type, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: Meh, while standard and portable, I recommend against INFORMATION_SCHEMA, mostly because they're incomplete: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand - you have a point, I use them up to the point I can't, then spelunk the system tables.

Comment: see and I don't see the point of that. Why use something when inevitably you'll need to switch gears? If you start with the catalog views, you don't have to change tactics when you come across something that INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't bother to cover. Kind of like having a cheese allergy, but eating cheese until it makes you sick. I'd rather just pretend that cheese (and INFORMATION_SCHEMA) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 45):

```
SELECT t.name 
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE s.name = N'schema_name';
```

Comment: This does not limit to tables 'populated by user'.

Comment: @jtimperley Well, I assumed "populated by user" was in reference to tables created by a user using a specific schema. In any case, what system tables do you see returned by this query? If you enable diagram support, `is_ms_shipped` is 0 for `sysdiagrams`, so your filter doesn't exclude it either.

Comment: (Not that `sysdiagrams` or any other system tables added, e.g. `systranschemas` which is created when CDC support is added, would match any schema other than `dbo` anyway.)

Answer (score 14):

SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 or 2014:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

For more details:
[How do I get list of all tables in a database using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT t1.name AS [Schema], t2.name AS [Table]
FROM sys.schemas t1
INNER JOIN sys.tables t2
ON t2.schema_id = t1.schema_id
ORDER BY t1.name,t2.name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.objects o on o.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

Comment: You should be able to run it just like that but you're free to make whatever changed needed.  :)  Filter outputted columns, add extra filters, derive table sizes, whatever.

Comment: This does not limit the results to a specific schema.

Comment: I like this for the `o.is_ms_shipped` filter.

Answer (score 1):

When you want just the name of the table the easiest  way is I guess just doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

when need like full name with schema and table name , than just do like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from [schema_name].sys.tables
```

This should work. Make sure you are on the server which consists of your `"[schema_name]"`

Comment: When I run this I get "Invalid object name 'dbo.sys.tables'."

Comment: The same for me

Comment: This works fine, when you enclose your DB name with square brackets. For example, using *sqlcmd*, you can do: `sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\mydb" -Q "SELECT * FROM [mydb].sys.tables;" -u -W`.