# is this possible in SQL to locate where actual data sits?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

HI I don't know that this is possible. but maybe,

I want to locate a column within a table, if it has this data:

'Ready' - the issue I am facing is the application appointment table holds the person who scheduled the appt. under

```
Date_Created and Operator_id.
```

But it does not show in this table who confirmed the appointment.
However, in the screen application there is one entry which states 'Ready' this is considered the confirmation.

But I cannot locate which table it might be in.

(and it could be a code but somewhere I would see 'READY' as data, ) this is what I am trying to accomplish, is there a way? Not the column name begin 'READY' but actual data.

Comment: I think you can start by looking to all tables you have on your database, which I think is sql server. look to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312331/list-names-of-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-2012-schema

Comment: so if I Can see which tables are open at application time? there used to be a tool called spy i think, would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite few ways you can follow, here is quick and easy one I can suggest.

Run the SQL Profile, do the UI operations and see what all SQL Queries or stored proc use, stop the Profiler and pick those queries, and you can make sense out of it.

This is better than building a giant query using `Sys.Tables` or `Sys.columns` and running a heavy operation on Non Index columns.

And remember, sometimes in the UI you would see DataTransformation like in the Database, it will be `"R"` as status, but on UI it will be transformed to `"Ready"`; or this value will be derived on the fly all together based on other column value logical operation.

So, give SQL Profiler a try.

If you don't have access to SQL Profiler, then you will have to explore other heavy operational approaches.